# MySQL - How to get one row from a table with multiple columns with true or false

Tags: mysql

I´m trying to write a query to get in a single row the records with values equals to TRUE in several columns. I thought it will be easy but it´s becoming though.

Having a table like this:

```
ITEMS   COL1    COL2    COL3    COL4    COL5    COL6
----------------------------------------------------
ITEM1   TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
ITEM1   FALSE   FALSE   TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
ITEM1   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
ITEM1   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   TRUE
ITEM2   FALSE   TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
ITEM2   TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
ITEM2   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   TRUE    FALSE   FALSE
```

I need to get something like this:

```
ITEMS   COL1    COL2    COL3    COL4    COL5    COL6
----------------------------------------------------
ITEM1   TRUE    FALSE   TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   TRUE
ITEM2   TRUE    TRUE    FALSE   TRUE    FALSE   FALSE
```

I tried using `distinct` and `group` with in a single table, something like this:

```
Select distinct ITEMS, COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4,COL5,COL6
FROM TABLE
WHERE   (COL10=’TRUE’  or COL2=’TRUE’ or COL3=’TRUE’ or COL4=’TRUE’ or COL5=’TRUE’ or COL6=’TRUE’)
GROUP BY ITEMS
```

But it doesn´t work, also I tried doing joins to the same table but the results were the same, it’s showing FALSE in columns with TRUE.

So, can somebody give a hint about how can I get the desired result?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what are you looking to get, records where at least 1 column is `true`?

Comment: If you group by ITEMS, last row will over-write any previous if ITEMS value same. try to delete "GROUP BY ITEMS"

Comment: Thanks, but if I remove the GROUP BY ITEMS then I will get several rows for the same item, and I need one row per ITEM with the columns with TRUE as value

Answer (score 1):

MySQL doesn't have aggregation functions for booleans.  However, these are really 0 (for false) and 1 (for true) in disguise.  So, try `max()`:

```
select items, max(col1), max(col2), max(col3), max(col4), max(col5), max(col6)
from t
group by items;
```

If these are stored as strings, then -- by coincidence -- the above actually works because `'TRUE'` > `'FALSE'`.  You could be more methodical:

```
select items,
       (case when max(col1 = 'TRUE') > 0 then 'TRUE' else 'FALSE' end) as col1,
       . . .
from t
group by items;
```

Comment: +1 but for what it's worth `0=false` and `1=true` is a MySQL-ism. Not supported in standard SQL and most other databases.

Comment: It looks like he's actually storing strings in his table, not booleans.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, that worked perfectly, also thanks to @Bill Karwin for the note about this just works only in MySQL

Comment: @CarlosH, remember to upvote answers that are helpful, and click the accepted answer checkmark for the answer that solved your problem in the best way.

Answer (score 0):

```
select items, min(col1), min(col2), min(col3), min(col4), min(col5), min(col6)
from t
group by items;
```

or

```
Select distinct ITEMS, COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4,COL5,COL6
FROM TABLE
WHERE   (COL10=’1’  or COL2=’1’ or COL3=’1’ or COL4=’1’ or COL5=’1’ or COL6=’1’
GROUP BY ITEMS

Dont use boolean in the Database
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `MAX()`, since `'TRUE'  > 'FALSE'`?